# WebRTC P2P stream a youtube video

Tags: youtube, camera, video-streaming, webrtc

I started learning about the WebRTC and interested if the API could be used for peer-to-peer streaming of a Youtube video for example. I could not find any articles on this. Would it be possible to use the API to stream and synchronize a Youtube video to two people in real-time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you will not be able to use YouTube as a WebRTC peer. The media stream from YouTube will not be able to perform the STUN and DTLS exchanges or setup the required SRTP stream.

What you could do is write a custom application that acted as an intermediary between YouTube and WebRTC peers. The custom application would need to be able to pull the stream down from YouTube and then forward it to any WebRTC peers that connected to it.

Answer (score 0):

You need an intermediary gateway to do that.
I have read on [this page](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1170491/How-to-broadcast-a-web-cam-to-YouTube-using-HTML-a) you can convert WebRTC stream to RTMP H.264+AAC for YouTube Live.They use Flashphoner.